# Why the icon is inserted crookedly into the button. С# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design

[image]

[image]

XAML:

```
        <Grid Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF1368BD"  >

        <Button x:Name="ButtonPowerOff" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="22" Width="22" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Click="ButtonPowerOff_Click">
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Width="15" Height="15" Kind="WindowClose" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 0 0 0" ></materialDesign:PackIcon>
        </Button>


    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the height and width of the button to "auto" and also set the padding to "0" in the button. Also delete the HorizontalAlignment of the icon.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what library is PackIcon, and that's is important because I don't know it behaviour. But I can tell...

Why do you set the PackIcon size if you have set the Button size?

The problem here is button maybe has default padding making the "effective content" size of the button smaller than image, and the image is doing what you want but "the space needed is greater than i have".

Let the image stretch in the button (without setting the size of it) or let the button fit the image 15x15 size (without setting the size of the button).

Everything in WPF is ready for sizeless/locationless layout. Except Canvas children, of course; and some bizarre behaviour of Image control.
If you can avoid use Width and Height in your controls (sometimes you can't) you should do it. Instead use margins, alignments and paddings. This way you let the window and controls be totally responsive.

Comment: The icon appears only if I set Width 40+.
I tried your suggestion, but nothing has changed.
Maybe just not use PackIcon.
Are there other libraries with Icons?

Comment: I repeat, I don't know what library are you using, or if that library overrides Button style or something. I'll try setting "HorizontalContentAlignment" and "VerticalContentAlignment" and "Padding" in the button to "Stretch" and "0". And see if the icon is visible.